# golang - Marshal key to PKCS5

Tags: go

I have a use case where some of our network devices can only accept an RSA key in PKCS5 format. However, no built in function is able to generate it in Go, e.g. `x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(privateKey)`.

Is there a way to output a key in PKCS5 format by setting the right headers, etc? I'm not well versed enough to know what is ASN is required, etc.

Comment: PKCS5 is not really a format.  Can you provide a bit more detail on exactly which device you are using and what this key is for?

Comment: As far as I know, PKCS5 allows you to embed a password inside the key. That's perhaps the only difference,  but I am not clear how to generate it. Here's how I convert it manually: ```openssl rsa -in rsa.pkcs8.key -out rsa.pkcs5.key```

Comment: I am quite intrigued by this. One problem I have when re-producing your issue is that the command `openssl rsa -in rsa.pkcs8.key -out rsa.pkcs5.key` removes the password from a key ([man page](https://helpmanual.io/man1/openssl-rsa-ssl/)). So when I use your command, I get a normal PEM key as output. *Unless* you are also passing in one of the options `-aes128`, `-aes256`, etc? While you cannot share contents, can you confirm the Headers **before** and **after**, please? (e.g. "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----")